# Lightning out with error 500 on NodeJS server

Tags: aura, oauth2, connected-apps, lightning-out, node.js

I'm tring to outsource my aura component with lightning out using a connected app but I have a 500 error. (**I have no problem connecting with the user/password/token mode**). CORS are well set (localhost:5000 here)

[image]
[image]

I tried to setup logs in salesforce but I have nothing but I can see connection success

[image]

Lightning out script :

```
<head>  
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="https://******.lightning.force.com/lightning/lightning.out.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="auraLightning"></div>
</body>

<script>
    $Lightning.use(
        "c:ParentDDCApp",
        function(){
            $Lightning.createComponent(
                "c:ParentAura",
                { msg: "It works (Aura)2!",
                callback : lightningCallback 
            ,
                "auraLightning",
                (cmp) => {
                    console.log("Aura component was created");
                }
            );          
        },
        "https://**********.lightning.force.com",
        "myToken"
    );
    //Function to call from Lightning Component
    function lightningCallback(theMsg){
        console.log('On WebSite: ' + theMsg);
        alert(theMsg);}


</script>
```

My aura app ParentDDCApp :

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp">
  <aura:dependency resource="c:parentDDCAura"/>
</aura:application>
```

My Aura component parentDDCAura:

```
<aura:component >
   <aura:attribute name="msg" type="String" default="No Message passed!" />
Hello

</aura:component>
```

I think the problem is with the connected app parameters but can't find how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem : the profile we used to display the componnent was **"API Only"**, what **doesn't work to display Lightning out component**. When we display it with a standard "read only" profile and the Permission set for the objects use by the compenent, we dont have the problem anymore.

Reminder : verify to use https://*********.lightning.force.com format in the script for connexion